# the meaning of the adverb 'willfully'

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

In a passage from *The future is bright for human, New Scientist* 2012.3.5, there is a sentence

> Perhaps willfuly, it may be easier to think about such lengthy
> timescales than about the more immediate future.

I am confused with the word 'willfully'. I have looked up that its adjective form 'willful' means 'sticking to one's own opinion' or 'deliberate', but the adverb form of both entry can't fit the sentence. So how to understand the 'willfuly' here?

Comment: You have to register to view the whole article, but using Google's cached copy from March 11, I see a different word: "Perhaps perversely...". That edit would make more sense. Perhaps you've simply found a bad word choice that has since been corrected.

Comment: What @Andy said. Regardless of whether the actual original had ***willfully*** or ***perversely*** (or indeed, some other equivalent, such as ***contrarily***), I think there's no doubt ***perversely*** is the better choice on purely stylistic grounds. But I think the construction is a bit flaky in this exact context anyway. We'd normally expect a "fronted" optional adverbial clause like *Perhaps **mistakenly...*** to be immediately followed by the relevant subject and verb ***...the author thought** it made his text look more erudite*.

Comment: (That's to say - the "existential it" here isn't being "wilful" or "perverse", so the construction doesn't really work very well for me.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers As long as we're editing, I'd go with "Perhaps counterintuitively," which maybe was what the original author was reaching for all along. "Counterintuitive" = "This doesn't appear at first to make sense, but it really does." "Perversely" = ascribes sentience and volition. We might use it for non-sentient subjects via personification, but that's not really what's going on here.

Comment: @AndyBonner: I think arguably there's a significant *semantic* difference between ***perversely / wilfully / contrarily*** and ***counterintuitively***. If the original writer had used any of those first three, I'd always vote for ***perversely*** as the "preferred" stylistic choice if I thought the writer was reasonably articulate. There's at least *some* difference between a "perverse" perspective (which acknowledges that *hardly anyone* ever sees things that way), and a "counterintuitive" one - which the present reader might only find "odd" *until he has been enlightened*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah, but [the context](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Ix5xgfiggeQJ:https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg21328543-600-the-future-is-bright-for-humanity/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) seems to me to suggest that the only thing proposed as "perverse" is "the existential 'it'," not the thinking.

Comment: @AndyBonner: Yes - I didn't mean to imply that I would always prefer one of "my" three alternatives *in the exact context as cited* (I didn't have access to that *full* context anyway). All I meant was I think there's at least a difference in "allusion / implication" between ***counterintuitively*** and the others. But my point about *the "existential it" here isn't being "wilful" or "perverse"* was nothing to do with the semantics - that was just by way of explaining why I think the exact construction as cited is syntactically / idiomatically "awkward" to both me and Nick Bailey below.

Comment: Is it worth mentioning that the preferred spelling is `wilfully` in all the main varieties of English from outside North America?

Comment: @aboves thanks for your answers! Besides, could you please explain the meaning of 'perversely'? I have looked up that 'perverse' means 'behaving in an unreasonable way', so its subject should be a person. If 'perversely' is used instead of 'wilfuly', what does it mean? @ Andy Bonner

Comment: A better definition is "strange and not what most people would expect or enjoy" (Cambridge Dictionary). A situation can be perverse with this meaning.

Comment: Thanks, this indeed makes more sense. @MichaelHarvey

Answer (score 2):

Here willfully means 'deliberately' or 'intentionally.' The idea the sentence is expressing is that we often chose to think about the more distant future, rather than, the near future.

I will note, the sentence is grammatically correct but seems awkward to me.

Comment: I'm not convinced the construction ***is*** "grammatically correct". But at the very least, I agree it's "awkward", and probably best avoided by learners.